# Increase spacing between legend groups with patchwork settings

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, legend-properties, patchwork

UPDATE:
The suggested code here

```
p1 + p2 + p3 + plot_layout(ncol = 1) + 
  plot_annotation(tag_levels = 'a') &
  theme(legend.justification = "left")
```

returned this

[image]

I need to have the legend groups aligned with the respective plots and I'm using this example from: https://gotellilab.github.io/GotelliLabMeetingHacks/NickGotelli/ggplotPatchwork.html

The desired output would have a larger space between the d4 and d2 groups, such that d4 is aligned with panel a and d2 panel b.

```
library(devtools)
install_github("thomasp85/patchwork")
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

d1 <- runif(500)
d2 <- rep(c("Treatment","Control"),each=250)
d3 <- rbeta(500,shape1=100,shape2=3)
d4 <- d3 + rnorm(500,mean=0,sd=0.1)
plotData <- data.frame(d1,d2,d3,d4)
str(plotData)

p1 <- ggplot(data=plotData) + geom_point(aes(x=d3, y=d4, color = d4))# + theme(legend.position = "right")

p2 <- ggplot(data=plotData) + geom_boxplot(aes(x=d2,y=d1,fill=d2))# + theme(legend.position = "right")

p3 <- ggplot(data=plotData) +
  geom_histogram(aes(x=d1, color=I("black"),fill=I("orchid"))) #+ theme(legend.position = "right")

p1 + p2 + p3 + plot_layout(ncol = 1, guides = "collect") + 
  plot_annotation(tag_levels = 'a') & theme(legend.position = "right")
```

[image]

The closest I could get is manipulating `legend.key.height` with `& theme(legend.position = "right", legend.key.height = unit(2, "cm"))`, but this isn't ideal because the legends are still center-justified and it would be very time consuming to nudge the `unit()` command so the legend height is the same as the respective panel's.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `legend.justification` in your `theme` instead of the `guides = "collect"` to have your legends aligned with its plot like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

p1 <- ggplot(data=plotData) + geom_point(aes(x=d3, y=d4, color = d4))# + theme(legend.position = "right")

p2 <- ggplot(data=plotData) + geom_boxplot(aes(x=d2,y=d1,fill=d2))# + theme(legend.position = "right")

p3 <- ggplot(data=plotData) +
  geom_histogram(aes(x=d1, color=I("black"),fill=I("orchid"))) #+ theme(legend.position = "right")

p1 + p2 + p3 + plot_layout(ncol = 1) + 
  plot_annotation(tag_levels = 'a') &
  theme(legend.justification = "left")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-05-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks. I didn't get what you got.

Comment: Uncomment # + theme(legend.position = "right") solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe `ggarrange` is an option for you:

```
library(ggpubr)

ggarrange(p1, p2, p3, 
          labels = c("A", "B", "C"),
          ncol = 1, nrow = 3)
```

[image]